# Execute program programmatically

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, programming, labview

I want to program our Ev3 for FLL (class assignment), and I want to use an object oriented approach in a very procedural environment. Is there a programmatic way to execute another program inside the same project using the augmented LabView? (This is more like using other programs as methods rather than programs, and then calling the "methods" to do a certain task like pull a lever, push a button, move the wheels...)

Comment: to clarify, I only can use LabView, unfortunately we can't use C++ or Java.

Comment: As a general note, LabVIEW is a dataflow-driven language, rather than OOP or procedural.  Just like OOP is a great aid for certain situations, using a dataflow-driven language is helpful for control system programming.

Comment: see what I didn't realize before is I can make my own blocks with the Ev3. That's how I have other "Programs" to execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of a LabView answer than a Mindstorms answer, but you should be able to create a SubVI that represents a task, and then you can place that in the main VI.

This help document might be useful:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372962A-01/lvnxt/creatingusingsubvi/